# Transfer Data from ASP:NET MVC Controller to view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an object in contrroller and I want to use them in view and in javascript code but I can't achived using ViewBag. my code hear :

```
public class MyController : Controller
{     

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://api/controller/....");
            ViewBag.VB = response;
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

and my view :

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

@section Javacript
{

<script type="text/javascript">

function MyFunction() {
 ****   //I want to use DATA hear.  *********
};
</script>
}
<div id="info">

</div>
```

How can I do this? Anyone have an idea?

Comment: [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: You can access model inside JavaScript functions. Do you know that? It might simplify answer.

Comment: Good point @yoda, you can access it from inside the JavaScript function via `var data = '@(ViewBag.VB)';`. The method provided in my answer works also when you don't embed the JavaScript code directly in the cshtml file, but in a seperate `.js` file.

Comment: thanks for comments. I am new in MVC so I don't now that @Yoda . And I have no model in this project, I get datas from web Api url via controller and I use them in view so I don't need any model. am I wrong?

Comment: I didn't know that I can use data in javascript like that ' var data= '@(ViewBag.VB);' @terabaud . thanks for answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your data into a `<script type="text/html">` node and access it from javascript via `document.getElementById`

```
<script type="text/html" id="data">@ViewBag.VB</script>

<script>
function MyFunction() {
    var data = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;
    // if the data is in the json format, you can use JSON.parse:
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    // TODO: do something with data
}
</script>
```

You can also insert the data directly into javascript:

```
function MyFunction() {
    var data = '@(ViewBag.VB)'; // or omit the single quotes if it's json data
    // TODO: do something with data
}
```

This approach requires that the javascript code is embedded into the `.cshtml` file.

Another possibility is to retrieve the data directly from javascript with an ajax request. This example uses jQuery's [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function:

```
function MyFunction() {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/api/controller/...",
         contentType: "application/json", // tell the api-controller that we want json
         dataType: "application/json",    // tell the jQuery callback that it is json
         success: function (data) {
             // TODO: do something with data
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @terabaud. the first one solved my problem.